# how to properly test ActiveMQ topic publishing

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm struggling to test that my code is publishing message correctly on the topic. I know that I could JMeter or whatever; but I want to have tests in the codebase, running against an embedded broker. Initially it was a Spring-based solution, however, to simplify it all, I've provided a minimal reproducible solution [here](https://github.com/62mkv/activemq-integration-test)

The gist of the code is:

```
    @Test
public void testPublisherService() {
    final String payload = "test-dummy-message";
    JmsTemplate destinationTemplate = buildJmsTemplate();
    JmsTemplate sourceTemplate = buildJmsTemplate();
    sourceTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(10000);
    JmsPublisherService service = new JmsPublisherService(destinationTemplate);

    log.info("Going to publish message");
    service.send(TOPIC_NAME, payload);
    log.info("Message is published");

    log.info("Going to retrieve message");
    Object retrieved = sourceTemplate.receiveAndConvert(new ActiveMQTopic(TOPIC_NAME));
    log.info("Message is retrieved");

    Assert.assertNotNull(retrieved);
}
```

and it fails! i.e. null is always received from the topic! I've added a DEBUG logging for ActiveMQ and it also did not help too much:

```
2018-12-19 10:17:37.393  INFO   --- [main] ru.mkv.jms.JmsPublisherIntTest           : Message is published
2018-12-19 10:17:37.393  INFO   --- [main] ru.mkv.jms.JmsPublisherIntTest           : Going to retrieve message
2018-12-19 10:17:37.393 DEBUG   --- [ActiveMQ VMTransport: vm://test_broker#1-1] o.a.a.broker.jmx.ManagementContext       : Unregistering MBean org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=test_broker,destinationType=Topic,destinationName=test_topic,endpoint=Producer,clientId=clientId4.74703049017198,producerId=ID_EEW00163-52272-1545207456632-4_1_1_1
2018-12-19 10:17:37.393 DEBUG   --- [ActiveMQ VMTransport: vm://test_broker#1-1] o.a.activemq.broker.TransportConnector   : Publishing: vm://test_broker for broker transport URI: vm://test_broker
2018-12-19 10:17:37.393 DEBUG   --- [ActiveMQ VMTransport: vm://test_broker#1-1] o.a.activemq.broker.TransportConnector   : Publishing: vm://test_broker for broker transport URI: vm://test_broker
2018-12-19 10:17:37.399 DEBUG   --- [ActiveMQ VMTransport: vm://test_broker#1-2] o.a.a.broker.region.AbstractRegion       : test_broker adding consumer: ID:EEW00163-52272-1545207456632-4:1:2:1 for destination: topic://test_topic
2018-12-19 10:17:37.400 DEBUG   --- [ActiveMQ VMTransport: vm://test_broker#1-2] o.a.activemq.broker.TransportConnector   : Publishing: vm://test_broker for broker transport URI: vm://test_broker
2018-12-19 10:17:37.400 DEBUG   --- [ActiveMQ VMTransport: vm://test_broker#1-2] o.a.activemq.broker.TransportConnector   : Publishing: vm://test_broker for broker transport URI: vm://test_broker
2018-12-19 10:17:37.400 DEBUG   --- [ActiveMQ VMTransport: vm://test_broker#1-2] o.a.a.broker.region.AbstractRegion       : test_broker adding destination: topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Topic.test_topic
2018-12-19 10:17:37.402 DEBUG   --- [main] o.a.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory    : Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Session Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@3e27ba32[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]

2018-12-19 10:17:47.405 DEBUG   --- [main] o.a.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer     : remove: ID:EEW00163-52272-1545207456632-4:1:2:1, lastDeliveredSequenceId: -1
2018-12-19 10:17:47.406 DEBUG   --- [ActiveMQ VMTransport: vm://test_broker#1-2] o.a.a.broker.jmx.ManagementContext       : Unregistering MBean org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=test_broker,destinationType=Topic,destinationName=test_topic,endpoint=Consumer,clientId=clientId4.74703049017198,consumerId=ID_EEW00163-52272-1545207456632-4_1_2_1
2018-12-19 10:17:47.407 DEBUG   --- [ActiveMQ VMTransport: vm://test_broker#1-2] o.a.a.broker.region.AbstractRegion       : test_broker removing consumer: ID:EEW00163-52272-1545207456632-4:1:2:1 for destination: topic://test_topic
2018-12-19 10:17:47.407  INFO   --- [main] ru.mkv.jms.JmsPublisherIntTest           : Message is retrieved
2018-12-19 10:17:47.408  INFO   --- [main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.3 (test_broker, ID:EEW00163-52272-1545207456632-0:1) is shutting down
```

I suspect it has to with connection/broker lifecycle which I am not ver much aware of.. or may be the retrieval approach. By the way ActiveMQ docs seems to be very limited in scope, I was unable to find any in-depth documentation as of how it actually works..

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. You are sending the message to the topic before any subscription exists. A message sent to a topic with no subscriptions is simply discarded. This is how topics work. You need to create a subscription, send the message, and then retrieve the message from the subscription. Aside from that you can switch to using a queue instead of a topic. If you did that I would expect your test to run fine.

Also, you may consider just using the JMS API rather than Spring on top of the JMS API as it may be simpler.

Comment: this was my primary hypothesis $)) thanks! Will check. Also, in the other project I was publishing to a QUEUE, have had my code pick it up from queue and publish on topic, and listened on the topic. Apparently that was also flawed, but as it took production code some time to process and publish the message, my test code managed to subscribe and I did not encounter any errors. I will check and approve of the answer if it all works